# How to use Imagemagick to convert a purple iconset to blue

Tags: imagemagick-convert

I have an iconset with a base color of purple that need to be converted to blue. The problem is that there are some icons have some pixels with opacity that I will keep (the opacity)

[Example](http://wprentals.javearentals.nl/wp-content/themes/wprentals/img/default_user_small.png)

Anyone knows the correct batch command to do this with imagemagick?

Answer (score 0):

I am using a V7 version but this should work on later V6 versions.

```
magick default_user_small.png -colorspace gray -auto-level +level-colors skyblue.png
```

Not my code I found it on the Imagemagick forums a few years ago. Before I was using Hue but it was always a bit hit and miss getting the correct values.

EDIT: I missed the bit about transparency, although your supplied image does not have any transparency